# Aligning buttons on a screen

Tags: blackberry

I would like to layout two buttons side by side and have multiple rows of these buttons like so -

```
B1 B2
B1 B2
B1 B2
```

For this do I need to combine VerticalFieldManager and HorizontalFieldManager somehow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `TableLayoutManager` class to support such type of layouts.
[TableLayoutManager.java](http://code.google.com/p/qrcoder/source/browse/blackberry/src/com/blackberry/toolkit/ui/container/TableLayoutManager.java?r=ae0257b8aad8c231d80cf34a244e402b3fecee22)
You can download and copy it in your porject and use it.
Use `TableLayoutManager` like this.

```
TableLayoutManager btnManager= new TableLayoutManager(new int[ {TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE, TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE},Manager.FIELD_HCENTER);
btnManager.add(B1);
btnManager.add(B2);
btnManager.add(B1);
btnManager.add(B2);
```

you can even define your number of columns and there layout styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JDK 5.0 or greater, there's [GridFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/GridFieldManager.html).  If you're using anything below 5.0, you'll have to use nested Vertical/Horizontal field managers.